# Let me guys know

Tags: grammar, expressions, idioms

I'm a native English speaker and I recently caught myself saying 'let me guys know', then immediately realized that it makes no grammatical sense whatsoever. My question is whether this is actually an expression that people use that I picked up somewhere or if I just had a moment of word vomit. Because right now I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: hi and welcome! A clarifying question: What did you mean by this phrase?

Comment: Were you trying to say "Let me know, guys" (Hey fellas, let me know) or "Let my guys know" (Tell my friends). If the latter, did you grow up watching SpongeBob?

Comment: It's not an expression I've seen before. If I heard it I would assume the speaker had made a mistake and try to figure out what they really meant from context (most likely one of the two options Damila mentioned).